# If an Old One takes damage while attacking my farm, do I get credit for it?

Tags: auztralia

AuZtralia includes the following personality card:

> Alanza Castro
>   Whenever an Old One attacks one of your Farms, it suffers two damage.

The rules don't say and we couldn't find an answer online: if I have this card in play and an Old One attacks my farm, do I get credit for the two points of damage?  In a game today, an Old One with four hit points died entirely from attacking two of my farms, and we weren't sure whether I got to collect the victory points.

The wording is passive (it suffers damage, as opposed to "you deal damage"), but as far as we've seen (only played a few games so far), all other damage dealt to Old Ones is "owned".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you get the credit for killing the Old One exactly as if you had attacked it.

This was verified by Martin Wallace the game designer in [this thread on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2072910/questions).